# How to read/write a hard disk when CPU is in Protected Mode?

Tags: windows, linux, operating-system, kernel

I am doing an OS experiment. Until now, all my code utilized the real mode BIOS interrupts to manipulate the hard disk and floppy. But once my code enables Protected Mode, all the real mode BIOS interrupt service routines won't be available.

I have a feeling that I need to do some hardware drivers now. Am I right? Is this why an OS is so difficult to develop?

I know that hardware is controlled by reading from and writing to certain control or data registers. For example, I know that the "Command Block Registers" of a hard disk range from `0x1F0` to `0x1F7`. I am wondering whether the register addresses of so many different hardware devices are consistent on different platforms? Or do I have to detect that before using them? How would I do that?

Since I am not sure about how to read/write a floppy or a hard disk in Protected Mode, I have to use BIOS interrupts to load all my necessary kernel files from the floppy before entering protected mode. What could I do if my kernel file exceeds the real mode 1M space limit?

How do I read/write a hard disk when the CPU is in Protected Mode?

Comment: You could see how an existing OS such as Linux (http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) or *BSD (http://fxr.watson.org/) handles that.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko I wouldn't advise ***anyone*** to read linux source code for the purpose of learning..  MINIX may be a better idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a feeling that I need to do some hardware drivers now. Am I right?

Strictly speaking; (and depending on your requirements) "need" may be too strong - in theory you can switch back to real mode to use BIOS functions, or use a virtual8086 monitor, or write an interpreter that interprets the firmware's instructions instead of executing them directly.

However, the BIOS is awful (designed for an "only one thing can happen at a time" environment that is completely unsuitable for modern systems where its expected that all devices are able to do useful work at the same time), and the BIOS is deprecated (replaced by UEFI), and it's hard to call something an OS when it doesn't have control over the hardware (because the firmware still has control of the hardware).

Note that if you do continue using BIOS functions; the state of various pieces of hardware (interrupt controller, PCI configuration space for various devices, any PCI bridges, timer/s, etc) has to match the expectations of the BIOS. What this means is that you will either be forced to accept huge limitations (e.g. never being able to use IO APICs, etc. properly) because it will break BIOS functions used by other pre-existing code, or you will be forced to do a huge amount of work to make the BIOS happy (emulating various pieces of hardware so the BIOS thinks the hardware is still in the state it expects even though it's not).

In other words; if you want an OS that's good then you do need to write drivers; but if you only want an OS that doesn't work on modern computers (UEFI), has severe performance problems ("only one thing can happen at a time"), is significantly harder to improve, doesn't support any devices that the BIOS doesn't support (e.g. sound cards), and doesn't support any kind of "hot-plug" (e.g. plugging in a USB device), then you don't need to write drivers.

> Is this why an OS is so difficult to develop?

A bad OS is easy to develop. For example, something that is as horrible as MS-DOS (but not compatible with MS-DOS) could probably be slapped together in 1 month.

What makes an OS difficult to develop is making it good. Things like caring about security, trying to get acceptable performance, supporting multi-CPU, providing fault tolerance, trying to make it more future-proof/extensible, providing a nice GUI, creating well thought-out standards (for APIs, etc), and power management - these are what makes an OS difficult.

Device drivers add to the difficulty. Before you can write drivers you'll need support for things that drivers depend on (memory management, IRQ handling, etc - possibly including scheduler and some kind of communication); then something to auto-detect devices (e.g. to scan PCI configuration space) and try to start the drivers for whatever was detected (possibly/hopefully from file system or initial RAM disk, with the ability to add/unload/replace drivers without rebooting); and something to manage the tree of devices - e.g. so that you know which "child devices" will be effected when you put a "parent device" to sleep (or the "parent device" has hardware faults, or its driver crashes, or the device is unplugged). Of course then you'd need to write the device drivers, where the difficulty depends on the device itself (e.g. a device driver for a NVidia GPU is probably harder to write than a device driver for a RS232 serial port controller).

For storage devices themselves (assuming "80x86 PC") there's about 8 standards that matter (ATA/ATAPI, AHCI and NVMe; then OHCI, UHCI, eHCI and xHCI for USB controllers, then the USB mass storage device spec). However, there is also various RAID controllers and/or SCSI controllers where there's no standard (each of these controllers need their own driver), and some obsolete stuff (floppy controller, tape drives that plugged into floppy controller or parallel port, three proprietary CD-ROM interfaces that were built into sound cards).

Please understand that supporting all of this isn't the goal. The goal should be to provide things device drivers depend on (described above), then provide specifications that describe the device driver interfaces (possibly/hopefully including things like IO priorities and synchronization, and notifications for device/media removal, error handling, etc) so that other people can write device drivers for you. Once that's done you might implement a few specific device drivers yourself (e.g. maybe just AHCI initially - everything else could be left until much later or until someone else writes it).

Comment: Thanks for describing the relation between an OS and device drivers for an OS. And the key aspects an OS should provide for device drivers.

Comment: So many years have passed since I asked this question. And this is the best answer so far as I think. Today I mark it as the answer. Life is too short. Hope I can make something interesting about OS. Thanks.

Comment: I am still not happy with the answer. I had collected some links about reading disks directly from the PM. My goal was to do this via AHCI controller. Not only to discover that 
 oldies in my digital pile of archived stuff!

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily HAVE to write drivers. You could drop back into real mode to call the BIOS service, and then hop back into protected mode when you're done. This is essentially how DPMI DOS extenders (DOS4GW, Causeway, etc) work.

The source code for the Causeway DOS extender is public domain, you can look at that for a reference.  http://www.devoresoftware.com/freesource/cwsrc.htm

Comment: This doesn't answer the question most relevant/specified in the title.

Comment: Yeah, it almost seems like all resources on OS development are avoiding this question by all sorts of gimmicks :q